# Creating JPanel dynamically

Tags: java, jpanel

I want to create JPanel as a part of JFrame

```
private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add((new JPanelSql("testName" , "testTxt")) , "cell 1 2,grow");

    }
```

---

```
class JPanelSql extends JPanel {

    private String name ; 
    private String txt ; 

    public JPanelSql (String name , String txt ) {
        this.name = name ; 
        this.txt = txt ;
    }

    public void createJPanel () { 


        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel(name);
        super.add(lblNewLabel);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(); 
        textArea.append(txt)   ;
        super.add(textArea);
    }

}
```

However, this does not create any JPanel in the JFrame .

How can I create a JPanel dynamically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `createJPanel` in your constructor...

```
public JPanelSql (String name , String txt ) {
    this.name = name ; 
    this.txt = txt ;
    createJPanel();
}
```

This will create and add your components to the panel...

Comment: `cell 1 2,grow` what is that? in `BorderLayout` and i don't think that is `dynamically` way.

Comment: Yep i think migLayout , the question is that he never set :P.. and i don't see in this answer the `dynamic` way , i guess by dynamic is based in an event. :P

Comment: it is miglayout . sorry i did not mention

Comment: @nachokk I'd "guess" it's a process of a watered down example leaving in/out elements...

Comment: @nachokk Lol. It's because the OP cut down there example, removing things they did think were relevant...